# How do I install an older version on Debian systems?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra, but i don't need the latest version 4.0.9, i need 4.0.5

I tried the below steps

```
cat cassandra.sources.list
deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 40x main

apt-get install cassandra=4.0.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.0.5' for 'cassandra' was not found
```

When I install without mentioning any version, it is installing 4.0.9, what should i do if i need to install specifically 4.0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background

Last year (July 2022), we moved the Debian and RPM repositories from downloads.apache.org to Apache's JFrog Artifactory server ([CASSANDRA-17748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17748)). For whatever reason, only the latest release of each major Cassandra version is presented by JFrog.

#### Symptom

I am able to replicate it using this source:

```
deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 40x main
```

After running an `apt-get update`, I can only see the latest 4.0 package which at the time of writing is C* 4.0.9:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy cassandra
cassandra:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.9
  Version table:
     4.0.9 500
        500 https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 40x/main amd64 Packages
```

#### Workaround

I haven't been able to work out why this is happening so I don't have a solution for you. However, you can workaround it by downloading the package from the [Apache Archive](https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/) then install it with `dpkg`.

#### Other

As a side note, we encourage you to deploy the latest patch release. I acknowledge that this is unrelated to the issue you asked but C* 4.0.5 is quite old (released in July 2022) and there have been dozens of fixes deployed since including important security patches.

For example, there is an issue with native protocol v3 which caused paging issues fixed in C* 4.0.8 that is highlighted in [`NEWS.txt`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/NEWS.txt) you should be aware of.

You can also see the long list of fixes released since C* 4.0.5 including patched CVEs in [`CHANGES.txt`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/CHANGES.txt). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Erick, I planned to go with 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you already did the `sudo apt-get update -y` post adding the repositories prior to installing the `4.0.5` version?

Steps:

1. `echo "deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 40x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list`
2. `curl https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -`
3. `sudo apt-get update [-y]`
4. `sudo apt-get install cassandra=4.0.5 [-y]`