# How do I install Cassandra on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: cassandra

```
Err:1 https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian 40x/main amd64 cassandra all 4.0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 88.99.95.219 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian/pool/main/c/cassandra/cassandra_4.0.5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 88.99.95.219 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 3):

The steps aren't fully clear on what was done and when did we hit this error.

Anyways, installing instructions are available at https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html

TL;DR

- `echo "deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 41x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list`
- `curl https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -`
- `sudo apt-get update -y`
- `sudo apt-get install cassandra -y`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the old repository as the source.

Last year (July 2022), we moved the Debian and RPM repositories from `downloads.apache.org` to Apache's JFrog Artifactory server ([CASSANDRA-17748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17748)).

If you have a look at the official [Apache Cassandra Download](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) page, there is a message that warns you about it:

> ⚠️ Debian and RedHat package repositories have moved!
>
> Debian’s `sources.list` and RedHat’s `cassandra.repo` files must be updated to point to the new repository URLs (see below).

We also announced the change in [Changelog #18](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-Changelog-18-August-2022.html) and [Changelog #19](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-Changelog-19-September-2022.html).

The new repository URLs are:

- Debian - `https://debian.cassandra.apache.org`
- RPM - `https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org`

Unfortunately, there appears to be an issue with the JFrog repository and only the latest release of each major version is available to install (see my response to [How do I install an older version on Debian systems?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327231/)).

As a workaround, you will need to download the `4.0.5` package from the [Apache Archive](https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/) and install it with `dpkg`. Cheers!